# Using variables PHP

Tags: php

So, this is part of the code in my sendemail.php and it works perfectly:

```
$email = $_POST["email"];

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: <webmaster@example.com'>' . "\r\n";
```

When trying to edit the From: to the email received from my form the script suddently it doesn't work. Could you help me?

I tried this:

```
$email = $_POST["email"];

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: <"$email">' . "\r\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this line:

```
$headers .= 'From: <"$email">' . "\r\n";
```

It should be:

```
$headers .= 'From: <"' . $email . '">' . "\r\n";
```

Because the contents of the variable are in single quotes, `$email` becomes a literal "$email" which is at least causing problem with receiving the email as spam filters will usually raise a red flag when it sees this.

Comment: + for speed, but you should add more detail.

Comment: Was in the process of doing it as you wrote this. :)

Comment: Hmm, the email hasn't reched it's destination, however it does when hardcoding an email adress insted of using $email.

Comment: That's explained in my answer so I am unsure what you're trying to say

Comment: Ohh, missed that one, but how do I make this without the single quotes then?

Comment: `$headers .= "From: <\"$email\">\r\n";`

Answer (score 0):

Another way to deal with variables in highly formatted content is to use [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php):

So the example that John Conde gives looks like this:

```
$headers .= 'From: <"' . $email . '">' . "\r\n";
```

But using `sprintf` it would look like this:

```
$headers .= sprintf('From: <"%s">' . "\r\n", $email);
```

The benefit is you do not have to worry about balancing quotes.  And since the variables are always at the end of the line, it makes it a tad easier to review for debugging in my opinion.

EDIT: Also, since this formats it better but is still not sending (according to the original poster’s comments) try the following variations instead. No quotes:

```
$headers .= sprintf('From: <%s>' . "\r\n", $email);
```

No `<` and `>`:

```
$headers .= sprintf('From: %s' . "\r\n", $email);
```

Comment: The email doesn't get sent, however it does when hardcoding an example email adress.

Comment: Still no success, this is weird..

This is the default W3Schools sample that works perfectly:
$headers .= 'From: <webmaster@example.com>' . "\r\n";